# Класс-конструктор-как реализовать?

Tags: c#

Есть несколько классов  с параметрами, задача-один из них заменить или добавить класс-конструктор
Задачка лёгкая, уровня начальной школы, но что-то глуплю

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace newproject
{
class Program

{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Human Katya = new Human();
        Katya.Hands = 10;
        Katya.Legs = 40;
        Katya.Head = 80;
        int SummKatya = Katya.SummOfParts();
        Console.WriteLine(SummKatya);


        Human Anna = new Human();
        Anna.Hands = 10;
        Anna.Legs = 40;
        Anna.Head = 80;
        int SummAnna = Anna.SummOfParts();
        Console.WriteLine(SummAnna);

        Human Victoria = new Human();
        Victoria.Hands = 100;
        Victoria.Legs = 100;
        Victoria.Head = 66;
        int SummVictoria = Victoria.SummOfParts();
        Console.WriteLine(SummVictoria);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

    public class Human 
    {
        public int Hands;
        public int Legs;
        public int Head;

        public int SummOfParts()
        {
            int SummOfPart = Hands + Legs + Head;
            return SummOfPart;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие несколько классов вы имеете в виду? И что на что заменить?

Comment: или "Arms and Legs", или "Hands and Feet"

Comment: Вам фабричный метод или абстрактную фабрику сварганить треба?

Comment: Добавить конструктор в класс? =)

Comment: Вы пишите "_есть несколько классов с параметрами_", но в коде у Вас только один класс `Human`, больше нет. `Katya`, `Anna`, `Victoria` - экземпляры. Так же `классов с параметрами` и `классов конструкторов` не существует, есть методы с параметрами, конструкторы с параметрами и свойства/поля. Поэтому Вас достаточно сложно понять, но видимо Вам нужен [просто конструктор](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173115.aspx). Но вы бы лучше уточнили, что надо.

Answer (score 1):

Паттерн называется **Prototype**

```
public abstract class Human : ICloneable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Hands { get; set; }
    public int Legs { get; set; }
    public int Head { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Девушка: {Name}-{Hands}-{Legs}-{Head}";
    }

    public int SummOfParts()
    {
        int SummOfPart = Hands + Legs + Head;
        return SummOfPart;
    }

    public abstract object Clone();

}

public class Woman : Human
{

    public override object Clone()
    {
        //здесь так для упрощения, на самом деле
        //тут нужно делать копирование всех свойств
        return this.MemberwiseClone() as Human;
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //первая девушка (будет образцом)
        Woman Anna = new Woman()
        {
            Name = "Anna",
            Head = 66,
            Hands = 100,
            Legs = 100
        };

        Console.WriteLine(Anna.ToString());

        //клонируем девушку
        Woman Natasha = (Woman)Anna.Clone();
        //изменяем имя
        Natasha.Name = "Natasha";

        Console.WriteLine(Natasha.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
        //выводит
        //Девушка: Anna-100-100-66
        //Девушка: Natasha - 100 - 100 - 66


    }
}
```